# Dynamically Setting Page Breaks So Blank Pages Don't Print

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet that is being used for quoting. I have 8 different pages that are all vertically aligned. I have page breaks set but when I decide I don't want a page I have it automatically hiding. However, since I have page breaks set, when I export to a PDF I get blank pages. I'd like to dynamically get rid of these blank pages when exporting to a PDF. I'm a mechanical engineer and haven't written much code so don't laugh too hard :).

I can write a concatenated function in excel to say which lines to insert page breaks above. The reason I like the cell being generating the page break numbers is if I insert a line later it will automatically update.
Here is what I belive the steps would be in VBA:

1. Remove all page breaks
2. Set column page break to the left of column AU
3. Set row page breaks based on the values generated by cell AX2

Here is what I have so far on the code which isn't quite working out.

```
ActiveSheet.ResetAllPageBreaks
ActiveSheet.Columns(47).PageBreak = xlPageBreakManual
ActiveSheet.Rows("AX2").PageBreak = xlPageBreakManual
```

For reference my formula for cell AX2==CONCATENATE(IF(AU76<>"",ROW(AU77),""),IF(AU199<>""," , "&ROW(AU200),""),IF(AU342<>""," , "&ROW(AU343),""),IF(AU403<>""," , "&ROW(AU404),""),IF(AU454<>""," , "&ROW(AU455),""),IF(AU507<>""," , "&ROW(AU508),""),IF(AU555<>""," , "&ROW(AU556),""),IF(AU597<>""," , "&ROW(AU598),""),IF(AU652<>""," , "&ROW(AU653),""))

Which at the moment is yielding 77 , 200 , 343

Also, I'm using this within the macro to export to a PDF. I'd insert this page break code before the export to pdf. Here is that code for reference as well:

```
Sub ExportToPDF()
'
' ExportToPDF Macro
'

'

    ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="Password"
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$5:$AU$652").AutoFilter Field:=47, Criteria1:="<>"
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$5:$AV$652").AutoFilter Field:=48, Criteria1:="<>"
    Dim Path As String
    Dim filename As String
    Path = "Destination"
    filename = Range("AY15")
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, filename:= _
        Path & filename & ".pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$5:$AV$652").AutoFilter Field:=48
    ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="Password", DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True, AllowFormattingCells:=True, AllowFiltering:=True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer here: https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/dont-print-hidden-rows.436254/page-2#posts

They did something very similar. The only thing I can't do with it is link it to cell AX2 to update on the fly as I insert or delete rows. SO, if someone knows how to edit my code to use cell AX2 to set this array I'd love to hear it! Here is my final code I put in:

```
Sub ExportToPDF()
'
' ExportToPDF Macro
'

'
ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="Password"
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$5:$AU$652").AutoFilter Field:=47, Criteria1:="<>"
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$5:$AV$652").AutoFilter Field:=48, Criteria1:="<>"
Dim pb, i As Integer

pb = Array(77, 200, 345, 406, 457, 510, 558, 600, 655)

ActiveSheet.ResetAllPageBreaks
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = "$A$1:$AT$654"
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.FitToPagesWide = 1
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.Zoom = 76
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.Orientation = xlPortrait
For i = LBound(pb) To UBound(pb)

    If ActiveSheet.Rows(pb(i)).Hidden = True Then
    ActiveSheet.HPageBreaks.Add Before:=ActiveSheet.Cells(655, 1)
    Else
    ActiveSheet.HPageBreaks.Add Before:=ActiveSheet.Cells(pb(i), 1)
    ActiveSheet.HPageBreaks.Add Before:=ActiveSheet.Cells(655, 1)
   
    End If
Next i
Dim Path As String
Dim filename As String
Path = "FileLocation\"
filename = Range("AY15")
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, filename:= _
    Path & filename & ".pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$5:$AV$652").AutoFilter Field:=48
ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="Password", DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True, AllowFormattingCells:=True, AllowFiltering:=True
End Sub
```